# How to use loop to repeat function choice

Tags: java

I am a new java leaner.
Right now, I am woking on a project which requires 4 functions.（like f1,f2,f3,f4)
After every function finished, I can choose which function to call next.
Actually I have done the 4 functions , but I don't know how to realize the function choice (I tried using nested while loop, but I messed it up)
I will appreciate if someone can just give me some ideas.
Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class driver
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("chosewhat you want");
    int a = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;
    ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
    Pet p = null;
    Person owner = null;

    while (a==1)
    {
    try 
    {
        objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("pet.dat"));
        owner = new Person();
        p = new Mammal();
        owner.getInput();
        p.owner = owner;
        p.getInput();
        objOut.writeObject(p);
        objOut.close();

        a = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();
    } 

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("here!!!");
    }
    }

    while ( a == 2)
    {
    try 
    {
        objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("pet.dat"));

        try 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                p = (Pet)objIn.readObject();
                System.out.println(p);
            }

        } 
        catch (EOFException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("System ends");
        }
    } 

    catch (Exception e)
     {
        System.out.println("something in driver");
    }
    a = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();

    }
}
}
```

above is my code,
If I press 1, the writing function has to be called , if I press 2, read function function has to be called, if I enter 3，function3(which I have not add yet) has to be called, but I don't know how to have a option choice after every function is finished, like after function2 finished, I can chose to do the function1,function2,function3 or exit the system.

Comment: Share your code so the community here can help you, and also state the result / output you want.

Comment: So you want user Input at Run Time to select the function to be Executed. You can use combination of switch and while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `do while` loop and `switch` to make decisions based on user input

```
public class Test{

  public static void main(String args[]){
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       int choice;

       do{
         choice = sc.nextInt();
         switch(choice){

           case 1: function1();
                   break;
           case 2: function2();
                   break;
           case 3: function3();
                   break;
           case 4: function4();
                   break;

          }

        }while(choice!=0);
   }

public static void function1(){/*definition*/}
public static void function2(){/*definition*/}
public static void function3(){/*definition*/}
public static void function4(){/*definition*/}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a collection of functions (methods) and choose which to call programatically, you can try the following:

First Create an interface with a method which will be used execute the function. Assuming your functions have one `int` parameter and return a `String`:

```
public interface IFunction {
    public String execute(int parameter);
}
```

Then you can define concrete functions by specifying `IFunction` through anonymous inner classes:

```
IFunction f1 = new IFunction() {

    @Override
    public String execute(int parameter) {
        return "Always this text";
    }
};

IFunction f2 = new IFunction() {

    @Override
    public String execute(int parameter) {
        return Integer.toString(parameter);
    }
};

List<IFunction> flist = new ArrayList<>();
flist.add(f1);
flist.add(f2);

int choice = 1; //This can be filled using user input;

flist.get(choice).execute(3);
```

By using an array, you can pass the user input directly to get.

Comment: @xiaopassion You can just use a switch, as suggested in the answer below, and call f1.execute(parameter) or f2.execute(parameter). The array I used is a way to show you how you can work with the functions as they were objects. This way, when you add new functions you don't need to add new  branches of `if` or `switch` control structures.

Comment: got you, Actually I haven't learned array yet,I will try this after I learn it, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use **"do while"** for repetition ,while the condition match ..**"if else"** for selection of the function

```
package com.loknath.lab;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Demo3 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("chosewhat you want");
        System.out.println("1 - F1");
        System.out.println("2 - F2");
        System.out.println("3 - F3");
        System.out.println("4 - F4");
        System.out.println("0 - exit");

        a = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (a == 1)
            f1();
        else if (a == 2)
            f2();
        else if (a == 3)
            f3();
        else if (a == 4)
            f4();
        else if ((a >= 5) || (a < 0))
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice: Please try again");
    } while (a != 0);
    System.out.println("Done");
}

public static void f1() {
    System.out.println("F1");
}

public static void f2() {
    System.out.println("F2");
}

public static void f3() {
    System.out.println("F3");
}

public static void f4() {
    System.out.println("F4");
}

 }
```